# Requiring original Sanskrit text when asking for explanation of translation?

Tags: discussion

Many questions are of the type :

*English translation of Gita* - *Why does Krishna say so?*

*English translation of verse* - *Is this valid today?*

and many times, the translations are incorrect either by accident (due to translator's brain), or by design (due to translator's heart).

None of us remember what lives we were leading when either the original Sanskrit works were written, nor when the events depicted by those works happened, nor when the translations were written.

Other than the original text, and their interpretations by acharyas, we have nothing to base on answers on, especially when there are conflicting ideas.

So, rather than expect the readers to look up the original verse, should the questioners take on additional responsibility of posting the original verse ?

Comment: Although your suggestion is good, i'm not sure if it is feasible, especially with new users or non hindus. But we can make it mandatory for answers, as answers need to precise than questions.