# Require quoting original texts/links in questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a question long back if we could require questioners to post [Sanskrit Text](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1173/requiring-original-sanskrit-text-when-asking-for-explanation-of-translation) of their quotations.

Can we require them to post links of the site when quoting ?

e.g. [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45815/will-a-sati-go-to-heaven-or-hell) and [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45793/is-rigveda-753-promoting-racism) attributes some quotes to some scriptures. They must have copied it from some website/book online. So, they must post that link in the question itself.

It is easy to get lost in translation. If answers are expected to have scriptural backing, questions which quote scriptures must also have link to said scriptures.

Comment: I think it is up to the OP but any high rep user can edit with proper links to make the question richer.

Comment: @Mr_Green - but if the OP is literally copy-pasting from a website, it is a 2 second job to paste that site link.

Answer (score 3):

> They must have copied it from some website/book online

If they have copied from some websites there should not be any reasons for them not to provide the online links. **So, in those cases they should (at least they can).**

But, I many times copy from PDFs and also hard copies of books in answers. In those cases, giving online links isn't possible. At the most, I can provide some links from which readers can know what is this scripture I'm quoting from.

So, if you want the proposed system to be made mandatory, then it's problem for some users like me.

For example, I'm quoting the following from a PDF of Mahanirvana Tantram:

> At the time of Ekoddishta Shraddha cooked rice and Pinda should be
> given whilst facing south. The rest of the ceremony is the same as
> that which has been already described, with the exception that sesamum
> should be substituted for barley (71). The peculiarity in Preta
> Shraddha is that the worship of Ganga and others is omitted, and in
> the framing of the Mantra the deceased should be spoken of as Preta
> whilst rice and Pindas are offered to him (72). The Shraddha performed
> for one man is called "Ekoddishta." In offering Pinda to the Preta,
> fish and meat should be added (73). O Mistress of the Kula! know this,
> that the Shraddha which is performed on the day following the end of
> the period of uncleanliness is Preta Shraddha (74). If there is a
> miscarriage, or if the child dies immediately on birth, or if a child
> is born or dies, then the period of uncleanliness is to be reckoned
> according to the custom of the family (75). The period of
> uncleanliness in the case of the twice−born is ten days (for
> Brahmanas), twelve (for Kshatriyas), and a fortnight (for Vaishyas);
> for Shudras and Samanyas the period is one month (thirty days) (76).
> On the death of an Agnate who is not a Sapinda, the period of
> uncleanliness is three days, and on the death of a Sapinda, should
> information of it arrive after the period prescribed, one becomes
> unclean for three days (77). The unclean man, O Primordial One! is not
> entitled to perform any rite relating to the Devas and the Pitris,
> excepting Kula worship and that which has been already commenced (78).
>
> Persons over five years of age should be burnt in the burning−ground,
> but, O Kuleshani! a wife should not be burnt with her dead husband
> (79). **Every woman is Thy image−−Thou residest concealed in the forms
> of all women in this world. That woman who in her delusion ascends the
> funeral pyre of her lord shall go to hell (80).** Kalika! the corpses
> of worshippers of Brahman should be either buried, thrown into running
> water, or burnt, according as they may direct (81). Ambika! death in a
> holy place or a place of pilgrimage, or near the Devi, or near the
> Kaulikas, is a happy one (82). He who at the time of his death
> meditates on the one Truth, forgetful of the three worlds, attains to
> his own Essential Being (83)

The bold portion is quoted in one of the questions you've linked. In this case, I can't give online links (although if I try I can get links too I guess from Google).

Comment: *"But, I many times copy from PDFs"* - but you must have downloaded those pdfs from somewhere, so u can link that site. The point is that, when we see a quotation, it must be genuine and link to a common source on the web that anyone can access. If a questioner copies from a website, just post that website also, it's not that hard..

Comment: Many of these PDFs have been downloaded years back. I tried sometimes to get online links but failed. If I'm quoting from a site then there is no reason why I should not provide that link. I always do that. @mar

Comment: yes, you do that, and i would like other OPs to do that when quoting as well.